# Select a specific Network Adapter on a Batch File

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, batch

I am trying to create a batch file that will always select a certain network adapter. I can't figure out the code to select the right one without prompting the user to select which one to select.

```
%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic.exe nicconfig where "Caption like '%Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz%'" call EnableStatic (“1.2.3.4”), (“255.255.255.0”)
```

I'm trying to make it where someone doesn't have to click anything and it will automatically select that network adapter and put in the IP and SubnetMask.
Any help will be very much appreciated. I am new to batch files. Here to learn.

Comment: You might see if the NETSH LAN commands will help you. You can put NETSH LAN in a batch file

Comment: what type of NETSH LAN commands would you suggest? Or is there an article you can post that would help me.

Comment: Try NETSH LAN CONNECT.

Comment: "The following command was not found: LAN CONNECT.
Enviroment variable Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz not defined

Comment: I will look around. I am not sure how else to automate.

Comment: Whenver I do WLAN and that command I'm allowed to set parameters and such but whenever I just do NETSH LAN CONNECT or otherwise it says "Invalid Command"

Comment: I am not certain - your LAN card may not be compatible.

Comment: I think it might be the connect. I can't find very many commands for NETSH LAN. I figure that is what it would be under.